# onEdit() stopped working?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, user-input

So I have a Google sheet where, when a user enters a number of an item, it will output a description and price. I actually have 50 sheets (one for each state in the US) that are all almost exactly the same, but put out slightly different prices because state taxes vary from state to state.

I used onEdit() to have my sheet work and it was working fine until I changed where the source for information came from. Originally in my sheet, I had another page with all the item information so that a simple Vlookup could do most of the work except calculate the item's price (this is what my code was doing, using the info page that was in the sheet to calculate a price).

However, when an edit needs to be made to an item, I want to make it so that we only have to update one "master" sheet, and make a call by openByUrl(...) instead of going to all 50 sheets and copy pasting the information. I tried implementing this in a sheet, and now it doesn't work when I edit, but it does work when I manually go into script editor and press run. What gives?

EDIT: Here's the code requested.

```
function onEdit(d) {
  itemPriceSetup();
}

// Runs the actual program.
function itemPriceSetup() {

  // Grabs and stores the sheet where a customer places an item number and where the code will output the price to.
  var orderSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Item Sale Doc");
  var orderSheetArray = orderSheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, 34, 8);

  // Grabs and stores the sheet that has the information on the item.
  //***var infoSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl('link to info');
 var infoSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("sheet with info");
 var infoSheetArray = infoSheet.getSheetValues(1, 1, infoSheet.getLastRow(), 10);
```

So the code with the three asterisks is what I want to use, but causes my the program to not work - that is, it onEdit() won't run (I have it commented out so the code will run - the line below it is the one I'm trying to replace). If I were to go through the debugger with the line un-commented, it actually works.

Comment: Please include the code you're using so we can see if you've made a typo, used a method improperly, etc.

Comment: I went ahead and made an edit. I think it might have something to do with permissions/limitations but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: A [simple trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/) has a few restrictions. One of which is that it cannot do anything that requires authorization. That's why your code wouldn't work with `SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(...)`--because using the `SpreadsheetApp` requires authorization.

Answer (score 3):

So I figured it out, but it's a bit strange. I didn't realize triggers for a script are found under resources, so I made put one straight in my script (I guess?). Either way, use the link and go to "Managing triggers manually" to read on how to do it.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable

Comment: Thanks, that's a real lifesaver.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem onEdit(e) wasn't working. After trying out many different things disabling the new Apps Script V8 engine worked for me. To disable go to Script-menu Select Run and click disable the engine

[Dissabling new Apps Script V8 engine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eSJy7.jpg)

I hope this answer will helps many. I appreciate all of the help that I've received on StackOverflow.Thank you